# Use \caption to show only the name of the picture

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to use `\caption` in figures only to show the name of the picture. Without **Figure 1.:** Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the package [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption). To remove the label load it as follows:

```
\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to acheive :). Thank you